# How to delete entity and its dependencies programmatically?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2015

My client have asked me to delete a custom entity and its dependencies (which prevents deletion of this entity) programmatically.

I have retrieved the dependencies of the custom entity using **RetrieveDependenciesForDeleteRequest**. This request is giving me the collection of dependencies, which must be deleted before the deletion of that custom entity.

```
                RetrieveDependenciesForDeleteResponse resp =
                    (RetrieveDependenciesForDeleteResponse) service.Execute(req);

                //A more complete report requires more code
                foreach (Entity dependencyEntity in resp.EntityCollection.Entities)
                {
                    service.Delete(d.LogicalName, dependencyEntity.Id);
                }
```

Now the issue I am facing here is that **dependencyEntity.Id** is always empty GUID, instead of valid GUID.

Can some one help me how to achieve this functionality?

Comment: Do you want to delete all of the dependencies or just remove the dependency? For example, if the entity to be deleted has a relationship where it is used as a lookup on another entity's form that is dependency you must resolve before deleting the entity. Presumably you don't want to delete that entity or the entity's form (just the lookup control on the form - which, btw, requires a publish.) If you know that no such dependencies (forms, views, dashboards, etc.) you'll probably be okay - if not, it's going to be hard to achieve in code. Hence, why MSFT doesn't handle it already.

Comment: Actually we have deleted all known dependencies (Relations, plugins, view etc. all of them) of this custom entity.. but when we try to delete this entity from UI.. it shows the popup message and says there are still some dependencies.. now we are not able to find these dependencies from UI.. so we thought of deleting it programmatically.
From UI.. it says there are some dependencies of type "SDK Message Processing Step"... but as I have mentioned we can't find it.

Comment: Those are going to be plug-in step registrations. You can look at them through the UI or fire up `PluginRegistrationTool.exe` to remove them.

Comment: Yes. I have already unregistered all the plugins (plugin steps) using PluginregistrationTool.. but still experiencing this strange issue.

Answer (score 2):

The `Entity` items in the response merely act as data transport objects. They are not real entities. What you are looking for is the attribute named "*dependentcomponentobjectid*" (this is a Guid type, not an EntityReference). Attribute "*dependentcomponenttype*" (OptionSetValue) gives you a clue about the type of the component you are dealing with.

Note that a dependentcomponent can in turn be a required component other components are depending on. (E.g. a workflow depends on a workflow activity, which in turn depends on a plugin assembly.) So, a robust removal tool would need to follow a recursive strategy.

Comment: How do you iterate over dependencies? Can't use Dependency since dependency is no class but MS example uses this approach in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.retrievedependenciesfordeleterequest?view=dynamics-general-ce-9

using var gives me logicalname dependency and no properties are filled. Strange.